# maximum call stack size exceeded jquery cytoscape

Tags: jquery, cytoscape.js

I am working with cytoscape and jquery with large data. My html code is

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.qtip.js"></script>
<script src="cytoscape.js"></script>
<script src="cytoscape-qtip.js"></script>
<script src="my_java_script.js"></script>`
```

My java script code is

```
$(function(){ // 
var cy = cytoscape({
container: document.getElementById('cy'),
boxSelectionEnabled: false,
autounselectify: true,
style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
.selector('node')
.css({'label': 'data(label)',
'width': '60px','height': '60px',      })
.selector('edge')
.css({'width': '10px','line-color':'#000000'})

.selector("#22").css({"line-color":"red"})
.selector("#44").css({"line-color":"red"})
.selector("#55").css({"line-color":"red"})
```

I have almost 20000 selectors. Because of such large data I am getting following error in Chrome 70 browser:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at k (jquery.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.D (jquery.js:2)
```

How can I get rid of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using classes for your selectors and not unique id's, the way you use them is not the way you are supposed to do that. Especially if the selectors are just a line color, you can always define the selector with a more dynamic option:

```
style: [
    {
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
            'shape': 'data(faveShape)',
            'content': 'data(DisplayName)',
            'height': 'data(faveHeight)',
            'width': 'data(faveWidth)',
            'background-color': 'data(faveColor)',
            'line-color': 'data(faveLineColor)',
            'font-family': 'data(faceFontFam)',
            'font-size': 'data(faveFontSize)'
       }
    },
    ...
```

]

And when you add nodes/edges, use the logic from your python code and get the color of the element, after that, just put that variable in the cy.add() and you are good to go:

```
cy.add({
    data: {
        id: 'yourId',
        ...
        faveLineColor: 'yourLineColor',
        ...

    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephan T. for your reply. I have different types of nodes and edges to be highlighted in different color. Can you please help me how to group them ?

Comment: If you do it like in my answer, there will be no need of grouping them, you just have to add a color field in the data part of your nodes/edges. I don't know what your data looks like (the data used for adding the nodes and edges to cy), if you can provide some sort of example that would be great :)#

Comment: I am adding data like this ,elements:{nodes:[{ data: { id:"n0",label:"A2" } },.....and for edges   edges:[{"data": {"id": "e0","source": "n2","target": "n0"}},

Comment: And how do you know which color each element has? Which criteria is responsible for that?

Comment: I am defining color by .selector. I have a python code which prints .selector commands in .js file. At present I am using .selector("#e19,#e2,#e5,#e4,#e9,#e15").css({"line-color":"blue"}) which is also not working for large data.

Comment: The important part is the WHY, why are e19,e2,... e.g the color blue, what do they have in common? Is there a specific reason/code, which color each node/edge gets?

Comment: Yes. They have some common feature. Python code check that feature and select the nodes and print the selected nodes in .js file

Comment: I edited the answer, should work like I decribed it, you can ask me if there are more problems

Comment: Hi @Stephan! Thank you for your help. Honestly speaking, I could not write the code in your fashion but managed to run it by groupingboth nodes and edges in following way: selector("#e19,#e2,#e5,#e4,#e9,#e15").css({"line-color":"blue"}). It is working for my present data. I may be back to you if I stuck again. Sorry for disturbing you.